# Constructor Returning Unnamed Object

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box {

     friend Box operator+(Box &box1, Box &box2);
public:

     Box(int L, int H, int W)
        :length(L), height(H), width(W) {
        cout << "\nBox constructor is executed";
     }

     void display() {
       cout << "\nLength = " << length;
       cout << "\nHeight = " << height;
       cout << "\nWidth = " << width;
    }

private:
     int length;
     int height;
     int width;
};

Box operator+(Box &box1, Box &box2) {
   cout << "\nFriend add operator is executed";

   int L = box1.length + box2.length;
   int H = box1.height + box2.height;
   int W = box1.width + box2.width;

   return Box(L, H , W);
}

int main() {
   Box firstBox(4, 5, 6);
   Box secondBox(3, 3 ,3);

   firstBox.display();
   firstBox = firstBox + secondBox;
   firstBox.display();

   return 0;
}
```

I found a code to understand friend functions. I understood it. However, I cannot understand what friend operator returns ? Some people say that it is unnamed object. Some of them say that it is constructor. Both of them do not sound reasonable. Please can anybody explain  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some people say that it is unnamed object

The correct term is *temporary instance*.

> Some of them say that it is constructor.

It's in fact a constructor call.

A constructor call outside of a variable declaration statement will create a *temporary instance* of `Box`, and that one is returned by value from the function.

Comment: You might want to link both ideas into a complete sentence so it's crystal clear :)

Comment: Thank you so much.